# Hive find out missing records in dimension table?

Tags: sql, hiveql

I am trying to find out which person have not installed the required software using Hive SQL.

### Here it is the script:

1. Records in table `t1` are software which different person actually installed.
2. Records in table `t2` include all required software.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (name STRING, install STRING);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2 (need_install STRING);
INSERT INTO TABLE t1 VALUES('Tom', 'Chrome'),('Tom', 'Ins'),('Tom', 'Cnn'),('Jane', 'Facebook');
INSERT INTO TABLE t2 VALUES('Chrome'),('Ins'),('Facebook');
```

### desired result

```
Tom  Facebook      # Tom have not installed the required software is `Facebook`    
Jane Chrome/Ins    # Jane have not installed the required software is `chrome` and `Ins`
```

### Solved

```
SELECT *
FROM(
        SELECT *
        FROM(
                SELECT DISTINCT NAME
                FROM t1
            ) tmp1
            CROSS JOIN t2
    ) tmp2
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON tmp2.name = t1.name
    AND tmp2.need_install = t1.install
WHERE t1.name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT X.NAME,T2.need_install FROM
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT NAME
   FROM T1 
)AS X
CROSS JOIN T2 
  EXCEPT 
SELECT T.NAME,T.INSTALL
FROM T1 AS T
```

Not sure if this works in Hive, but in SQL Server produces the desired result

Comment: It works good. Hive do not support `EXCEPT` function. But can instead with left join. I have updated my question.